# Vue.js select closest div with certain classname

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="app">
<div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Some overlay text</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="info">
    <h6 class="name">Title here</h6>
    <p class="meta">Meta here</p>
</div>
<div class="info-button" @mouseover="addParentClass" @mouseout="removeParentClass">
    Mouse over here!
</div>
```

What I would like to do is whenever someone hovers over the div with class "info-button" certain classes get added to the image above and the overlay.

I have got it working with the following Vue.js markup:

```
let vm = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data:{
    isHovering: false
},
methods: {
    addParentClass (event) {
        event.target.parentElement.children[0].children[1].classList.add('active')
        event.target.parentElement.children[0].children[0].classList.add('overlay-active')

    },
    removeParentClass (event) {
        event.target.parentElement.children[0].children[1].classList.remove('active')
        event.target.parentElement.children[0].children[0].classList.remove('overlay-active')
    },
},
})
```

However it seems like a lot of redundant JS. I have tried to get it working with:

```
event.target.parent.closest('.overlay'.).classList.add('overlay-active')
```

And a lot of similar parent/children/closest selectors, however I can not seem to get the result I want. How can I get the "closest" selector to work here?

Here's a codepen with a very rough working example: [Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/designdepot/pen/vQwYxM)

Edit: I want to point out that i want to use this in a loop, so I will have mulitple images and I want to make the overlay only appear on the current image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VueJS is reactive. This means the data should drive the DOM. You should not play with the DOM yourself.

Add an active property to data;

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data:{
        isHovering: false,
        active: false
    },
    methods: {
        addParentClass (event) {
           this.active = true;
        },
        removeParentClass (event) {
          this.active = false;         },
    },
})
```

And make the DOM reactive by;

```
    <div class="overlay" :class="{'overlay-active': active}" >
        <p>Some overlay text</p>
    </div>
```

Here is the updated codepen

https://codepen.io/samialtundag/pen/Jeqooq

Comment: I initially had that, however, this option makes an overlay over all images. So I can only use it with a single image. I should've added to the question that I want to use it on multiple images and make the overlay only appear on the currect image. Sorry.

Comment: I would than create an array in data section like   [{active: false, img: 'http://..'}, {active: false, img: 'http://..'}] and iterate over it to create the content.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind: Could you ellaborate why i should not play with the DOM?

Comment: Because in the long run, direct DOM manipulations and reactivity together will give you something unmanageable and complex. You have to take care of many things. My best bed for direct DOM manipulation would be using refs. If you are creating content only with VueJS, perhaps JQuery is a better option for you because VueJS is better on creating complex applications rather than content pages.