# Vue js: How to add a class to the closest td on click of Button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue coming off of JS/JQuery. I have a table, and each row has 2 possible buttons and two inputs, all wrapped in `<td>`. When I click a button I want the nearest input to have a class added. In JQuery I would have used the `closest` method in selecting the neighbouring `<td>` Here is my Vue template syntax. Many thanks!

```
<tbody>
                     <tr v-for="child in registeredChildren">
                        <td class="col-2"><a :href="'/getchild/'+ child.child_id">{{child.childFirstName}}</a>&nbsp &nbsp {{child.childLastName}}</td>

                        <!--========TIME IN===========-->
                       <td class="col-3 pb-2"}"><input style="text-align:center;" class="form-control editChild initial" type="text" v-model="child.timeIn" ></td>
                       <td><button v-on:click="updateTimeIn(child)" class="btn btn-outline-success">Reset</button></td>

                        <!-- //========TIME Out ===========//-->
                       <td class="col-3 pb-2" ><input style="text-align:center;" class="form-control editChild" type="text" v-model="child.timeOut" ></td>
                       <td><button v-on:click="updateTimeOut(child)" class="btn btn-outline-success">Reset</button></td>
                    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Methods: I was thinking if I could add some code to the UpdateTimeIn and TimeOut methods, this could be an approach?

```
 methods:{
        updateTimeIn(child){
         this.updatedChild = child;
        console.log(child.child_id,child.timeIn)


            axios.post('http://kidsclub.test/upDateChildTimeIn', {
                child_id: child.child_id,
                timeIn: child.timeIn,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },

**NB** I have the same for updateTimeOut
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what `registeredChildren` looks like? Is `child_id` unique?

Comment: Also, I think this answer describes a good way to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53617104/909973 You would have to create a component called like `childTableRow` and then pass a `child` object to it as a prop. Then you could have local variables in your `childTableRow` component to toggle classes in your template.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Vue, which unlike jQuery, means the data should drive the DOM. In Vue, you don’t have to consider selecting certain dom nodes.

I used to switch from jQuery to Vue, too. I have provided a demo, hope you can find ideas in it.

```html
<button @click="onClick">click me</button>
<div class="fixed-classes" :class="{'dynamic-class': isClick}"></div>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    isClick: false
  };
},
methods: {
  onClick() {
    this.isClick = !this.isClick;
  }
}
```

You can run it online through the code sandbox link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-class-6u0v4?file=/src/components/Example.vue)

I updated the code based on the comments in the code sandbox.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it has been enormously helpful. However, I have still having one major problem. on click, I need to apply the dynamic class to the input neighbouring it's button. At the moment on click applies the class to all inputs. I have done a little reading and I have tried adding  `:key="child.child_id" but this has not helped. I have provided an image to help you understand.  
[link](https://imgur.com/a/rzCVccD)  

MANY THANKS!! CHEERS!

Comment: Sorry it took me a long time to see the comments. I looked at the picture and changed the code in the code sandbox. Please click the validate button, the background color of the input below has been changed, and you can even control the valid variable to control different dynamic classes to display different colors, whether it is the effect you want. As I said in my answer, everything in Vue drives the change of the view with data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, however, sadly I could not make it work  in the sandbox. What I needed was when a button was licked, then ONLY the neighbouring input would be styled. At the moment when I click a button ALL inputs are clicked. I think I am going to give up on this in Vue and simply do it in JS / JQuery. Many Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for taking too much time to figure out the effect you want, my English is not very good, please forgive me. I think I have fully understood your needs this time.Please take a look at the code in the sandbox again, it can click reset to change the style of its adjacent input